# How to get repeatable HMAC hash with keyvault certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hash, azure-keyvault, x509certificate2

We need to get the `HMACSHA256Hash` as a string in .NET.

I need to get a repeatable (until it rotates) hash value for a given input to hash. I would like to use an Auto-rotatable keyvault cert as the key that is used to generate the HMAC has. It is ok for the hash function to return a different value once the cert rotates.

The `HMACSHA256Hash` constructor takes a `byte[]` as the key. I have the `X509Certificate2` object returned from a keyvault request. I have tried using the `X509Certificate2.Export()` method to get the `byte[]` to use as a key, however calling `Export()` twice on the same object returns a different byte[] by design in .NET.

What are my options for getting a deterministic `byte[]` from a given `X509Certificate2` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

> however calling Export() twice on the same object returns a different byte[] by design in .NET.

That depends on what format you export as.  X509ContentType.Cert will produce a fixed answer for a given input, which is just the certificate data (no private key info).  That same data is available on the `X509Certificate2.RawData` property.

Comment: good callout, but correct - I want my HMAC key to be a secret, so am looking to use the cert with the private key included.

I'm tempted to just save the first exported `byte[]` as a `base64 string` into a keyvault "Secret" and pull that secret down instead. If the secret serializes into a different pfx than is pulled from keyvault, that means the cert has rotated and we handle that as if it were a new key (reupload the `byte[]`)